# Youtube video size in grid theme

Tags: 7, theming, files

I am trying Omega and wondering if there is a way to specify the size of the Youtube video in grid terms, so I could easily show few videos next to each other (in a view for example).

Or if there is a way to make video automatically fit within a cell of a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the video's width to 100% via CSS should make it fit whatever width you've given its wrapping cell or div.

Check out the FitVids module / library for an all round solution to making videos behave better on responsive sites.

http://drupal.org/project/fitvids

http://fitvidsjs.com

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, I will try it. Do you know if it works with views?

Comment: Yes as far as I know.

Comment: Actually 100% width works as I can set it in `Media » File types » Manage file display` settings. But height does not work, it is always stays at some random value... I am not sure about the CSS suggestion, as this width eventually is being set in iframe.

Comment: You can override the value set in the iframe with CSS.

Comment: Alright that is not required then, as I can keep it in settings for now. Do you have any ideas on how to fix height?

Comment: If you don't mind about preserving aspect ratio just set the height to a pixel or percentage value. Otherwise fitvids may handle it for you (can't remember off the top of my head) or read up on intrinsic ratios I am css: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video